# Angular CDK Portal, multiple Portals to one PortalOutlet?

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

So as the title states, is it actually possible using Angular CDK portals/portalOutlets to attach multiple portals to one PortalOutlet, I've been digging through the CDK source code and can't seem to find anything that indicates that it's possible.

Mainly drawing this conclusion on this code within portals.ts.

```
attach(portal: Portal<any>): any {
  if(!portal) {
    throwNullPortalError();
  }

    if(this.hasAttached()) {
  throwPortalAlreadyAttachedError();
}

if (this._isDisposed) {
  throwPortalOutletAlreadyDisposedError();
}

if (portal instanceof ComponentPortal) {
  this._attachedPortal = portal;
  return this.attachComponentPortal(portal);
} else if (portal instanceof TemplatePortal) {
  this._attachedPortal = portal;
  return this.attachTemplatePortal(portal);
}
```

I can obviously create multiple portalOutlets or lets say overlays in this scenario and attach a component portal to each overlay individually using the componentFactoryResolver, but again not really the scenario I'm after.

Comment: What is the scenario you are after? A portal is, more or less, a rectangle of screen dedicated to a dynamically instantiated component or template. Why do you need multiple components at the same time? If you're working with overlays, you can still track multiple overlay instances at the same time, managing them from a coordinating service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's indeed not possible. What you could do is make one general container for your portals, then only attach/detach that container to the PortalOutlet depending if there are 1 or more portals to show.

You will have to create your own attach view logic, but it's pretty straight forward using the [viewContainerRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef)

Comment: So a colleague of mine was digging through the angular cdk site - https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview and noticed that if you inspect pages elements that there does indeed appear to be an overlay container with multiple overlay containers residing within it, if you could help elaborate on that as well, would be much appreciated.

Comment: And thank you for pointing me towards viewContainerRef does seem much more fit for purpose.

Comment: @Munerz you're welcome :) about the menu, if you are talking about the sub menus, these are all separate `TemplatePortals` (see [here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/08d78f9fbe3ce21c8e0d0ab78a4790d4ab08cc13/src/material/menu/menu-trigger.ts#L566)) projected in the `cdk-overlay-container`. That container is from the class `Overlay`, not `OverlayRef`. So at all time there will be only one `cdk-overlay-container` as you can see [here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/036729dc1a7b41236fcda9b23c578f9ef65b484c/src/cdk/overlay/overlay-container.ts#L54)

Comment: Hey guys, I am trying to achieve something similar. Can you please sare a Stackblitz?